# How do I get rid of excels ridiculous auto format when creating a file in php to excel format

Tags: php, excel

I have a program that makes the file a excel file and I have it so it gets rid of the dumb format mc excel but will not get rid of ########

That format happens in mc excel it seems if a cell has the symbol - in it.  But not all of them are like that.

Code for the cleaning up is :

```
function cleanData(&$str)
  {
   // escape tab characters
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);

    // escape new lines
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);

    // convert 't' and 'f' to boolean values
    if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
    if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';

    // force certain number/date formats to be imported as strings
    if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
      $str = "'$str";
    }

    // escape fields that include double quotes
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';

  }
```

Let me know if you need anything else!

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can start a cell's content with a single quote (') and it treats the content literally, and doesn't mess with it.

Comment: That "########" is what MS Excel displays when the content of a cell is too large for the default column size: it's nothing to do with symbols. The value in the cell is still correct, but you can't set a column width when using a tab-separated value file, so you have no control over this unless you switch to a real Excel file

Comment: PS. If you have to use a tab-separated value file; instead of writing your own conversion to tab-separated value, why not use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function instead?

Comment: Mark didnt know :) Thanks!  But ya your right when I click on it it displays data haha so simple but thanks!

Comment: Mark should submit his comments as answers so the OP can accept them and close the question. :]

Answer (score 1):

That "########" is what MS Excel displays when the content of a cell is too large for the default column size: it's nothing to do with symbols in the text. The value in the cell is still correct, but you can't set a column width when using a tab-separated value file, so you have no control over this unless you switch to a real Excel file.

If you have to use a tab-separated value file; instead of writing your own conversion to tab-separated value, why not use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function instead?